# Reduce on Range throws NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/IntIterator

Tags: kotlin

Test:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val total = (0..10).reduce { total, next -> total + next }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/IntIterator
    at TestReduceKt.main(TestReduce.kt:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.IntIterator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: What do you wish to achieve with this code?

Comment: @unicorn2 Nothing really, it's just a test. Should add all the values in the range and set total to the result.

Comment: Could you check the version of Kotlin plugin you're using, and the version of kotlin-runtime you depend on, and ensure they do match?

Comment: @Ilya Plugin version is 1.0.0-release-IJ143-70, how do I check the kotlin-runtime version? The path is config\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-runtime.jar so I guess it's just the one included in the plugin. Haven't changed anything from what idea setup.

Comment: I think IntelliJ gives you a warning if the version don't match, with a link/button to update things

Comment: http://try.kotlinlang.org/ returns the same error too. I don't think this is project setup problem.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me that should be raised on the kotlin issue tracker. For what it's worth, it works for me on 0.13.1513 but fails on 1.0.0 on my mac using command line tools.

Comment: Reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11153

Comment: i think the question should be deleted, a youtrack issue is enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11153) in Kotlin 1.0. It will be fixed in Kotlin 1.0.1.